# How to loop through an array of objects and get the values from a specific object?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

Basically I have an `array` of `objects` that I've managed to dump. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the values from the `[options]` object from a set `objects` and store them in an array

```
array(4) {
  ["size"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2724 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Size"
      ["options"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "400 ml"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "1L"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "2L"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(0)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["fruit"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2723 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Fruit"
      ["options"]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "Apple"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "Pear"
        [3]=>
        string(9) "Pineapple"
        [4]=>
        string(12) "Passionfruit"
        [5]=>
        string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
        [6]=>
        string(13) "Baobab Powder"
        [7]=>
        string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(1)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["good-source-of-vit-c"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2722 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(20) "Good Source of Vit C"
      ["options"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(2)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["fiber"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2721 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Fiber"
      ["options"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(3)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried doing a foreach to loop through each object but I've stumbled upon an error.

```
foreach ($productsArray as $i => $value) {
    echo $value->options;
}
```

My objective is to get all the values from the `[options]` object store them in an array to be used.

Comment: "options" a) isn't at the top level of the array, it's inside another array inside an object, and b) that array is protected, so you can't access it from outside the object anyway. Perhaps the object has a function defined on it which can be used to return the options data?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you are iterating over an array of `WC_Product_Attribute` objects and that's a sign of WooCommerce usage, isn't it?

In that case there is a getter method available to get options from a Product Attribute:

```
foreach ($productsArray as $i => $value) {
    var_dump( $value->get_options() );
}
```

More [in the docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Attribute.html#method_get_options)

Comment: Thanks for that, now I just need to figure out how I can loop through of these and store it

`array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "400 ml"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "1L"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "2L"
}
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Apple"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Pear"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Pineapple"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "Passionfruit"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "Baobab Powder"
  [7]=>
  string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Yes"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Yes"
}`